# Is that integer equal to the number in textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Xcode and Objective-C. I watched a tutorial where he compared a char with the entered text in the textfield of the simulator. He used the following code:

```
BOOL isUsersEqual = [self.username isEqualToString:[self.usernameTextField text]];
```

When trying to build a small app myself I have problems to get the number out of the Textfield and be processed into my code. I want it to compare the random number I generated to the number in the textfield. How can I accomplish that?

I know this is kind of a nooby question and I don't wanna ask every time. Is there someplace I can look up all those types of questions?

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far. Clarify what part you need help with. It is converting the entered text into an `int`? Is it comparing the `int` to the random number? Is it generating the random number? And searching here is a place to lookup these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by converting the number into string and then comparing -

```
NSString *number = [self.username stringValue];

if(number isEqualToString:self.usernameTextField.text){

   //Do Something

}
else{

   //Do Something

}
```

*But this method only works when you're comparing Equals To -*

For Greater than/ Less than/Equal to you can try it by converting the textfield's text into number and then comparing -

```
NSNumber *number = [self.usernameTextField.text integerValue];

if(number == self.username){

       //Do Something

    }
    else{

       //Do Something

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare your generated number with a number from textField, you must first typecast the textField text to NSInteger using

```
NSInteger b = [[textField text] integerValue];
```

then you can proceed to compare the 2 numbers.

To fully understand these types of questions, I recommend you learning about **objective-c primitive types** and **typecasting**. Good luck!

Comment: It's important to know that `b` will be `0` for any text that isn't a valid number.